# how can we do file operations in adobe flash builder using mxml script?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, mxml

I am using adobe flash builder 4.6. using fileReference.save(), we can create files. But it prompts a dialogue box for the location. Can we define it in the code and avoid prompt box. Is there any other method for doing file operations?

Comment: Avoiding the prompt would be a huge security risk! `FileReference` operations always require user interaction: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/user-interaction-required-upload-download.html

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible from Flex/Flash Player. If you want to operate on the file system, you have to switch to AIR.